# PHP error "expecting ')'" But can't seem to spot any

Tags: php

I am writing a php function with nested loops and I keep getting an error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INC, expecting ')'

```
function createCol5($diff) {
    $days = floor($diff/60/60/24);
    $digit = strval($days);
    $value1 = substr($digit, -1);
    $length = strlen($days);
    for($i= 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
        $temp = substr($digit, $i, 1);
        if($temp != 0) {
            for($h= 0; $h< $temp; h++) {
                echo "<br/><tr><td>*</td></tr>";
            }
        }
        //echo "<br/><tr><td>$temp</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

it keeps pointing to both if statements for the error. any insight?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your second `for statement` you are missing the `$` on `h++`:

```
for($h= 0; $h< $temp; $h++)
{
    echo "<br/><tr><td>*</td></tr>";
}
```

The reason you would receive this error is that if you were using `h`, it would be considered a constant, which is unchangeable. You wouldn't be able to increment the constant.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. I guess my eyes aren't adjusting after being in front of this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

The "h" in the second loop when you increment. Change it to "$h".

Answer (score 0):

pleas try this:

```
function createCol5($diff)
    {
        $days = floor($diff/60/60/24);
        $digit = strval($days);
        $value1 = substr($digit, -1);



        $length = strlen($days);

        for($i= 1; $i <= $length; $i++)
        {
            $temp = substr($digit, $i, 1);
            if($temp != 0)
            {
                for($h= 0; $h< $temp; $h++)
                {
                    echo "<br/><tr><td>*</td></tr>";
                }
            }
            //echo "<br/><tr><td>$temp</td></tr>";
        }
    }
```

in the for loop the variable h++ should be $h++

Comment: You _must_ make a note of what you changed, rather than just "try this". To the casual observer, your code looks identical to the OP's code.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski: Thank You for the suggestion. It was a valid one.